# What is the difference between the "up" vector and the y axis?

Tags: vector, three.js, 3d, projection

In ThreeJS, why do objects have an `up` property?
i.e. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.up

Isn't an object's `up` just its `y` axis?

Is there a difference between `up` and `y`?

Comment: Different 3D tools may have different directions for the Y and Z axis. Some 3D tools are Y-Up, which means the Y axis is a vertical line; while the others are Z-Up, means the Z axis is a vertical line.

Comment: There are reference systems where the up can be Z.